# why my filter in url is removed when i change page?

Tags: php, laravel

when i go to the next page (page 2) my filter (product = $category) is removed from my url

```
my url in first page //   /selectcategory?select=nailpolish
my url in page 2  // selectcategory?page=2
it should be // selectcategory?select=nailpolish&page=2
```

why select part removed ?

in controller

```
public function items(Request $request)
{
    $category=$request->get('select');
    // dd($category);
    $products = Product::latest()->where('product',$category)->paginate(30);
    $cobuns = Cobun::latest()->get();
    $tips = Tip::latest()->get();
    return view('products.index',compact('products','cobuns','tips'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 30);

}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values

Answer (score 2):

You should append your query strings in the controller by adding `withQueryString()`:

```
$products = Product::latest()->where('product',$category)
             ->paginate(30)->withQueryString();
```

More info: [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values)